# Capture log files that ended with any number

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find

We want to capture all logs that ended with ".log.[any number]

So I create this syntax

```
find .  -type f  -regex '\.log\.*[0-9]$' -print

command does not give any output
```

But this doesn't capture the files as the following ( expected results )

```
  controller.log.2018-01-03-01  
  server.log.2017-10-31-03
  server.log.2018-01-23-11
  server.log.2018-04-06-17  
  server.log.2018-07-07-05
  controller.log.2018-01-03-02  
  log-cleaner.log.10           
  server.log.2017-10-31-04 
  server.log.2018-01-23-12  
  server.log.2018-04-06-18 
  server.log.2018-07-07-06
  controller.log.2018-01-03-03 
  log-cleaner.log.2   
  server.log.232.434
```

what is wrong with my syntax ?

Comment: Try `'.*\.log\..*[0-9]$'`

Comment: this not works ( we have redhat 7.2 version )

Comment: Try `find .  -type f  -regex '.*\.log\..*[0-9]$' -print`, it seems to work.

Comment: Is it possible you can have `controller.log.text-here1` that you would not like to return? Then use `find . -type f -regex '.*\.log\.[0-9-]*[0-9]$' -print` to only return files with digits and `-` after `.log.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `find` manpage:

> `-regex pattern`
>
> File name matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match on the whole path, not a search.  For example, to match a file named `./fubar3`, you can use the regular expression  `.*bar.`  or `.*b.*3`, but not `f.*r3`.  The regular expressions understood by find are by default Emacs Regular Expressions, but this can be changed with the -regextype option.

So, you **must** match the whole path, in this case you could try with:

```
find .  -type f  -regex '.*\.log.*[0-9]$' -print
```

Comment: I think better to update to  find .  -type f  -regex '.*\.log.*[0-9]$' -print

Comment: for example it will match also the collector-gc.log-ferfwef , but we need to match the log with number that ended

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.(considering that your files are same format as shown samples)

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*\.log.[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){3}"
```

Comment: It doesn't match with `log-cleaner.log.2` nor `server.log.232.434`

Comment: ++ but you may avoid all ``\`` by using `-regextype posix-extended`

Comment: @Gioconda, that is why I mentioned warning that as per shown sample only I have written the regex. Let me know if that satisfies you(please remove the down vote in case you have done)

Comment: @anubhava, thanks sir but some how when I am trying to use that option I am getting error may be my system don't have it, request you to please edit answer as per your suggestion so that we all could be benefited from it too.

Comment: @Judy, could you please try `find . -regextype sed -regex ".*\.log\.[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}"` and let me know then?